# How to set cache drive on network for QWebView caching

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

I am using QWebView to display my web content, I wanted to setup cache capability for my webview for that I wanted to set cache drive, but I dont have enough memory available at my client side, how can I give some folder location located at my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [QNetworkDiskCache](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qnetworkdiskcache.html). Create one and [assign](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#setCache) it to an instance of [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) (which gets used through the web page object, see [QWebPage::setNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebpage.html#setNetworkAccessManager)).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I have looked at this API (QNetworkDiskCache::setCacheDirectory ( const QString & cacheDir )), but can I give network shared folder path here??? As I don't have memory at my client.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, there is no provision to give network shared folder path here, but world doesnt end here , we can map a network shared folder and can assign a drive letter to that.